# How could i render the html page into my ctp file?

Tags: cakephp

i have uploaded some html files in webroot folder of my cakephp project and the url becomes of this type:

http://mydomain.com/myproject/app/webroot/html/html_passport/somepage.htm

Now i want to provide this html page url to phone team. so that they can direstly view the page.

How could i render the html page into my ctp file. so that url becomes like

http://mydomain.com/myproject/controllername/actionname

Thanks

Comment: Why not just place the html into a ctp you have under a controller, then create a function to render the file found in the directory.

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this question? How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your HTML file is called `myfile.html`.

Copy myfile.html to `app/views/pages/myfile.ctp`

You will now be able to view the page at `http://mydomain/project/pages/myfile`

hope this will sure help you.